# Sending parameters through html form

Tags: html, post, get

I'm trying to send parameters with GET method but i cannot get the right response. These are parameters:
**name, email, importance, newsletter, message** 
and this is my HTML:

```
<form action="http://www.fulek.com/VUA/SUPIT/ContactUs" method="GET">
        <label for="name">Full name:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
        <label for="email">E-mail:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email">
        <label>Message importance:</label>
        <select style="border: 1px solid #ccc; border-radius: 4px; width: 
300px; height: 40px;" name="importance">
            <option value="high">High</option>
            <option value="mid">Mid</option>
            <option value="low">Low</option>
    </select>
    <label>Recieve newsletter</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" id="newsletter" value="yes" 
style="width:10%;">
    <br>
    <label>Your Message:</label>
    <textarea name="message" rows="10" cols="40" style="border: 1px solid 
#ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
    </form>
```

Comment: Please specify the problem.

Comment: Where is backend source code?

Comment: I have a local server set up and when i click the button to submit, the site in form action is giving me an error

Comment: i don't have backend source, in the assignment these are parameters and i have to use the exact markup that is in my code

Comment: whick kind of error?

Comment: @NadanMarenković — You're telling us that your code is correct but the server is giving you an error. You haven't told us what that error is. You've given no clues as to how what you have written could possibly be wrong (since all we know is that you think it is correct).

Comment: Why have you tagged this [tag:post]? You aren't making a POST request.

Comment: the error is that the data isn't passed correctly

Comment: @NadanMarenković - Given the information you've provided. How are we supposed to determine what "the data isn't passed correctly" *specifically* means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By googling the endpoint address in Google, I found a working example on github.

https://github.com/kelj0/Simple-FoodShop/blob/master/templates/index.html

From there you can find out that "newsletter" param is expected to be "true" and not "yes".
Change it to

```
<input type="checkbox" name="newsletter" id="newsletter" value="true" style="width:10%;">
```